# catch stderr and stdout in log4j before unix redirection

Tags: java, log4j, stdout, stderr

I'm using log4j in my application to log certain packages with a different log level.

However, stderr and stdout do not seem to be captured in this logfile, and instead they are being printed in a file when the app starts with

```
java AppName >> out.log
```

is it possible to catch stdout and stderr in log4j (e.g stdout as info and stderr as WARN/ERROR ) as well as in the out.log file?

Settings for log4j are as follows:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="FileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${MDCapture.logfile.dir}/${APP_NAME}.log"/>
        <param name="BufferedIO" value="false"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MMM-dd"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.TTCCLayout">
            <param name="DateFormat" value="ISO8601"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="AsyncAppenders" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
    </appender>

<!-- LOGGER PACKAGES -->

<root>
    <priority value="info"/>
    <appender-ref ref="AsyncAppenders"/>
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

**UPDATE:**

Stacktrace for stackoverflow error:

```
WARN root buffer size limit:65log4j:WARN root buffer size limit:65Exception in thread "Thread-12"
2013-03-22 09:14:24,451 [Thread-12] ERROR root - java.lang.StackOverflowError
2013-03-22 09:14:24,452 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:202)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,452 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:140)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,452 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:475)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,452 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:619)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,452 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:756)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,452 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.LogLog.warn(LogLog.java:171)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,452 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender.append(AsyncAppender.java:175)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,452 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,452 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)


2013-03-22 09:14:24,452 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,452 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,452 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:838)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,453 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at com.company.something.AClass.LoggingOutputStream.flush(LoggingOutputStream.java:198)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,453 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:432)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,453 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:202)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,453 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:272)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,453 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:85)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,453 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:168)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,453 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:477)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,453 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:619)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,453 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:756)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,453 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.LogLog.warn(LogLog.java:171)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,453 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender.append(AsyncAppender.java:175)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,453 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
2013-03-22 09:14:24,453 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To redirecting stdout and stderr to log4j, try something like this:

```
System.setErr( new PrintStream( new LoggingOutputStream( Logger.getRootLogger(  ), Level.ERROR ), true);

System.setOut( new PrintStream( new LoggingOutputStream( Logger.getRootLogger(  ), Level.INFO ), true);
```

For `LoggingOutputStream` you can start from [this example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4j/trunk/contribs/JimMoore/LoggingOutputStream.java)

To get log4j to print what you want to the console (and capture this back into a file/node if you want), enable a [ConsoleAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/ConsoleAppender.html) to the proper level

Comment: I've just tried those two lines, with the class from the link you provided, and I still can't see any System.err.print msgs in my log4j file.

Comment: Yeah, forgot the autoflush on the Printstream. Correcting above

Comment: this seems to have worked, with the only caveat that out.log does not have the stderr/stdout output anymore.

Comment: To get back log4j events to the your out.log, you need to add a ConsoleAppender

Comment: I seem to get a StackOverFlow error after using your solution. 2013-03-22 09:14:24,451 [Thread-12] ERROR root - java.lang.StackOverflowError
2013-03-22 09:14:24,452 [Thread-12] ERROR root -        at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:202). Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: We never had Log4j doing stack overflow errors (using a similar solution). Can you get a stacktrace ?

Comment: what is `com.db.mercury.InternalRateCapturer` ? It may be flushing a lot/too much  of datato the log.

Comment: that's the main class where System.setErr and System.setOut have been invoked. I am suspecting that it may be flushing a lot/too much to the log. I think this is caused by an external library being used. Thanks!

Comment: OK. The problem is likely with your AsyncAppender - check bufferSize on [this doc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#AsynchAppender)

Answer (score 5):

For log4j 2.x:

```
System.setErr(IoBuilder.forLogger(LogManager.getRootLogger()).setLevel(Level.ERROR).buildPrintStream());
System.setOut(IoBuilder.forLogger(LogManager.getRootLogger()).setLevel(Level.INFO).buildPrintStream());
```

Dependency Information:

- group: org.apache.logging.log4j
- artifact: log4j-iostreams